# Create a computed field using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Consider the following model for a EF 6 entity:

Id (int, nullable:false, identity: true)
Name (string)
Number (string).

I want number to persisted as combination of letter and id field. For example if during insert id valuse is going to be 1, I want number to be A00000001. I tried using DatabaseGenerated attribute on Number but that did not work. Problem is at time of insert EF will not know what identity value is. Is there a way to define a trigger to do so or is there some other method I can achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: try to insert first and then update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first inserting the item to the database:

```
  Item myItem = new Item(){Name = "MyName"};
  dbcontext.Items.Add(myItem);
  dbcontext.SaveChages();
```

Then bring the item from the database and update it:

```
  Item insertedItem = dbcontext.Items.Single(i => i.Id == myItem.Id);
  insertedItem.Number = insertedItem.Name + insertedItem.Id.toString();

  dbcontext.SaveChages();
```

Comment: I was really hoping I don't have to do this way. But it is what it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to save the computed field to the database and are using POCOs for Entities you can just define an unmapped field like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public string Number
{
    get { return Name + Id.ToString(); }
}
```